# django different table data merge

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

models.py
ex)

```
table1(models.Model):
   id = primarykey
   content = textfield
   registerdate = datetimefield

table2(models.Model):
   id = primarykey
   content = textfield
   plus1 = charfield
   plus2 = charfield
   registerdate = datetimefield
```

I tried

```
tb2 = table2.objects.all().values("id","content","plus1","plus2","registerdate")
tb1 = table1.objects.all().annotate(plus1=Value('plus1', output_field=CharField()),plus2=Value('plus2', output_field=CharField())).values("id","content","plus1","plus2","registerdate")
```

merge = tb2.union(tb1)

tb2 values is right

but tb 1 fields is strange.

some times `plus1 = plus1 , plus2=plus2`
some times `plus1 = plus2 , plus2=plus1`

I want

```
merge.count()
merge.order_by("-registerdate")
```

can I get consistent aligned field

if not

I can get count and order without union?

Comment: Well this basically sounds like a join, not a union, a union means you simply see the tables as two independent objects, and you somehow put these in the same table.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem i can't get two data totalcount and order registerdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your tables structure you wouldn't have this problem at all.
Consider the following:

```
table1(models.Model):
   id = primarykey
   content = textfield
   registerdate = datetimefield

table2(table1):
   plus1 = charfield
   plus2 = charfield
```

If you go with this you can get table1 and table2's count using
 `table1.objects.count()`
you can also get table2's count only using `table2.objects.count()`

You can also use `OneToOne` fields. Here is an example:

```
table1(models.Model):
    id = primarykey
    content = textfield
    registerdate = datetimefield

table2(models.Model):
    id = primarykey
    table1 = models.OneToOne(table1)
    plus1 = charfield
    plus2 = charfield
```

and now you can annotate with `F` objects on table2 like this

```
from django.db.models import F
table2.objects.all().annotate(content=F('table1__content'), registerdate =F('table1__ registerdate'))
```